# How do I create a switch statement - using a UISegmentedControl - to switch between view controllers?

Tags: swift, datasource, uipageviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UIViewController which features a UISegmented control placed in the nav bar to navigate between 2 vertical scrolling UIPageViewControllers. How do I implement a switch statement to switch between the view controllers delegated by the segment control?

```
lazy var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let control = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    control.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
    return control
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl
    addChild(self.forYouVC)
    addChild(self.followingVC)
    view.addSubview(forYouVC.view)
    view.addSubview(followingVC.view)
    didMove(toParent:forYouVC)
    didMove(toParent: followingVC)
}


@objc private func segmentControlValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        forYouVC.view.isHidden = true
        followingVC.view.isHidden = false
        
    case 1:
        forYouVC.view.isHidden = false
        followingVC.view.isHidden = true
    default:
        break
    }
}


private func setupView() {
    
}
```

}

Comment: Rather than creating 2 viewconrollers you can create one tableview controller and create 2 custom cell for respective view controller that you want and than you can simply realod the tableview on segment control did select

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn’t just use a UITabBarController. Set its tab bar to hidden. On change of segmented control, gset the selectedIndex to the index of the selected segment?